# Is there any reason why Git erasing my Django templates content?

Tags: django, git, github, visual-studio-code, django-templates

Before  I commit, I run—'git status', and I see Git erased my Django templates content (if that makes any sense). This strange behavior happens occasionally.

Can somebody explain what's going on?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*erased*"? Did you add the file through `git add ...` before commiting? Were the files commited and then "disappeared" later one?

Comment: It looks like you are using some IDE, probably on a Mac. This might be hiding a lot of details and your question might really be about that IDE. In any case you would definitely benefit if you found a [mcve]: some way for someone to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Turing85 I didn't add anything. Before running ```git add .``` I ran ```git status``` and I've noticed the whole content has been erased from a random Django template, as you can see from the picture above (which by the way I didn't modify at all). It's not the first time and the funny thing is that it happens only with Django templates. I can't explain why this happening and I'm sure it doesn't make sense for a lot of people.

Comment: @torek I'm using VSCode.

Comment: In that case, you probably have a VSCode question, not a Git or Django or GitHub question. VSCode does its own thing. (I don't use VSCode, but everything I read here on StackOverflow tells me that "avoid VSCode" is a good idea.)